# Как удалить значение SharedPreferences в другом Activity?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

В первой `Activity` я кладу значение в `SharedPreferences`

```
public class OneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static SharedPreferences settings = null;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;
    public static final String STORAGE_NAME = "StorageName";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        settings = this.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.putInt(id, 5);
        editor.apply();
}
```

Во второй `Activity` мне нужно перезаписать это значение

```
public class TwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static SharedPreferences settings = null;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;
    public static final String STORAGE_NAME = "StorageName";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        editor.remove("id");
        editor.putInt("id", 3);
        editor.apply();
}
```

Но у меня выходит ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor
>   android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.remove(java.lang.String)' on
>   a null object reference

Comment: Во второй Activity получите SharedPreferences и Editor так же как и в первой: `settings = this.getSharedPreferences(STORAGE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);`. И нет необходимости сохранять их в статические поля.

Comment: woesss, даже если так сделать editor  отображается как неопределенный

Comment: Так получите его снова: `editor = settings.edit();` Я ведь написал уже что нужно получить `SharedPreferences` и `Editor` так же как и в первой `Activity`